# Merge two seperate columns in Google Sheets into a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a list that contains people's names in one column and their company's names in a second column. At the top of each column there is a label, i.e "Name" for column A, "Company" for column B.

[image: Data I have]

The way a program I want to use works is to read data from a master list in one column, and it differentiates the type of data contained in the first column using second column, like this:

[image: Data I need]

The ultimate goal is to have this data pulled automatically from an outside source, which is stored on one tab. There will then be another tab containing this master list, one column containing people's names and various company names, and a second column with the first column's data type (i.e 'Person' or 'Company', as pictured above) right next to it.

So far I have been able to populate individual columns in the second tab by using Sheet's "QUERY" function,

```
`QUERY('Importer'!A2:A)`
```

which allows the column to update very nicely every time the other tab is updated from the outside source, the problem is that because I don't know ahead of time how long the referenced column is going to be, I can't add a second 'QUERY' function to pull data from another column below it.

Any tips on how to solve this would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY({IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"|Name"),IF(B2:B="",,B2:B&"|Company")},"where Col1 is not null")),"|"),2,0,1,1))
```

---

A little bit of explaination (inside-out):

- `IF()` - Create concatenated strings within a 2d-array using `{1,2}` construct.
- `QUERY()` - Remove all empty rows from the array.
- `FLATTEN()` - Flatten the resulting array into a single column
- `SPLIT()` - Turn the concatenated values back into a 2d-array.
- `SORT()` - Sort the returned array on both collumns to get the wanted result.
- `ARRAYFORMULA()` - Everything needs to be wrapped as an array entered formula.

---

**EDIT**

For those who want to play around with the data for themselves:

| Name | Company |
| --- | --- |
| Ash Quintana | Company A |
| Aubrey Wickens | Company B |
| Cameron Toth | Company C |
| Harley Holbrook | Company D |
| Jac Argent | Company E |
| Jamie Ziya | Company F |
| Jess Patel | Company G |
| Lane Bergman | Company H |
| Madison Taub | Company I |
| Troy Easton | Company J |

Comment: Yes! This did exactly what I needed it to do. The only thing I had to do was add '<sheetName>'! before both the references to the columns in the formula in order to pull in the data from another sheet. I'm assuming that's the best way to do that?
Much appreciated!